# Error creating a test project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, project

I get following error everytime I try to create a new Test Project:

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

### Failed to get service ITestToolSettingsManager.

### OK

I am currently running Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate with Feature Pack 2 on Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit.

I have also tried following with no avail:

- Run VS under admin mode
- Reset VS settings by going to Tools --> Import and Export Settings
- Run "devenv \setup" --> this fails
- Run "devenv \InstallTFSTemplates"
- Run "devenv \ResetSettings" --> this fails

Your help in resolving is much appreciated.

Kind regards,

HG

Answer (score 1):

Probably same deal I had File => new project test projects Fails.

Installed Templates => Visual C# => Test => Test Project

works

found answer at

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsunittest/thread/8739096e-afb3-4760-baeb-ae707fb3ab09

Comment: any feedback as to what the -1 is about?